# subsite link showing above the site icon

Tags: top-link-bar

For some reason this new subsite has added a link at the very top of the page. I have both the nav bars turned off. No idea how to remove it.

As you can see in the image the "Regional IT Security" subsite is listed right below the O365 bar but above the Site logo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it from Site Navigation settings.

Go to `Site Settings` --> `Navigation` --> `Global Navigation`.

Once you delete the subsite link from global navigation, it will not be visible above the site icon.